# Do background stuff without blocking the other thread

Tags: android, multithreading, andengine

I want to make some tasks on a thread without blocking the main thread. I'm using andengine and i want that while the users restarts the game a sprite with "saving score" shows up and my other thread starts and uploads the score if necessary. The game should wait this thread to finish without blocking its animations and when completed, call the restartClassicGameScene(engine) to restart a new game.

PS:I'm using an asynctask class with a json object to upload scores and it takes from 1 to 5 seconds to upload it, so i don't want to make the game look like it freezed

Edit: the question is:
How can i call the reloadClassicScene only after che runnable gas finished andò without blocking che uithread

```
        resetButton = new Sprite(10,260,resourcesManager.classic_reset_region,vbom) {
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                //MANAGE ONLINE SCORES

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        if(!resourcesManager.nickName.equals("a")) {

                            if(resourcesManager.checkUserConnectionStatus()) {

                                resourcesManager.getUserHighScore();

                            if(resourcesManager.onlineHighScore != -1) {

                                if(resourcesManager.onlineHighScore<score) {
                                    resourcesManager.setOnlineScoreInLocalWay(score);
                                    resourcesManager.setClassicOnlineScore(score);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    }
                });

                if(resourcesManager.volumeSwitch)
                    ResourcesManager.getInstance().clickButtonSound.play();
                SceneManager.getInstance().restartClassicGameScene(engine);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: And your *question* is?

Comment: How can i call the reloadClassicScene only after che runnable gas finished andò without blocking che uithread

Comment: @user3409801 AsyncTask